# update query where i have an list of ids for each id I want to get higest datetime

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query

```
update tableName set flag = True where id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and timestamp *does something*
```

the table contains ids, timestamp and a flag, the ids are not unique I extract them with a distinct subquery, so in the table I have reapeated ids. I want to update the flag for distinct id with the biggest timestamp.
Any pointers would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses a correlated subquery for filtering:

```
update tableName t
    set flag = True
    where t.id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and
          t.timestamp = (select max(t2.timestamp) from tableName t2 where t2.id = t.id);
```

Comment: god, how didnt I see that, thanks a ton! have a great weekend.